# Get user call logs in flutter

Tags: flutter, runtime-permissions, calllog

I am new to flutter currently i am creating a flutter application where user need to get call history, i have done this in in java(native app) but i have no idea how to do this in flutter . and one more thing how to get run-time permissions for this I have checked documentation of flutter but got nothing related to this.

thank you .

Comment: there is a package for that, https://pub.dev/packages/call_log/install
and it is basically a method channel calling some native android code.
but it is only available for android, they explained why IOS cannot in the pacakge readme

Comment: thanks for your response , i have checked this package and unable to understand the real implementation . could you please help me to do so or can you share some example regarding to this . thank you

Answer (score 1):

use call_log plugin available in pub.dev
here is the link : https://pub.dev/packages/call_log
the only problem here is that this plugin is only supported in Android.
you can use it like this

```
Iterable<CallLogEntry> _callLogEntries = <CallLogEntry>[];
_callLogEntries = CallLog.get();
```

do not forget to add call log permission in menifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```